# polyglossia and titling packages conflict

Tags: polyglossia, titling

I did some search with no chance about the problem I have using these two packages together. I use TeXStudio under Linux to write TeX docs.

This is the code I use:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
    \posttitle{%
        \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.4em}%
}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{draftcopy}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[heightrounded, headheight=114pt,marginparwidth=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[final,ulem=normalem]{changes}
\usepackage[block=none,style=philosophy-modern]{biblatex}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}
\addbibresource{my.bib}
\nocite{*}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Scheherazade}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}

\title{\textbf{My title}}
\subtitle{my subtitle}
\author{author\\
    email: my mail} 
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\section{bla}
\end{document}
```

This code works perfectly but when I add the `polyglossia` package, as in the example below, I get a bunch of errors and the subtitle disappears:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
    \posttitle{%
        \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.4em}%
}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{draftcopy}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[heightrounded, headheight=114pt,marginparwidth=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[final,ulem=normalem]{changes}
\usepackage[block=none,style=philosophy-modern]{biblatex}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}
\addbibresource{my.bib}
\nocite{*}
\usepackage[quiet]{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguages{arabic,greek,english,german} 
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Scheherazade}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}

\title{\textbf{\emph{My title}, cor gentile}}
\subtitle{my subtitle}
\author{author\\
    email: my mail} 
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\section{bla}
\end{document}
```

The solution for me about the subtitle was simply, but even removing the `titling` package the log reports a lot of errors with `polyglossia`, most relevant is related to `biblatex`:

```
Package biblatex Error: No default polyglossia language defined
```

even if, by contrast, both seem to work correctly.

Any clue how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your preamble is kind of a mess. The order the packages are loaded with is very important.

Here's a version with some comments: note that `cleveref` should be last. And, for your own sanity, only load packages you *do* need.

However, due to `bidi`, `titling` will ***not*** work, because the `bidi` package is not aware of it, so it overwrites its definition. You can check this by removing the `arabic` language option.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[heightrounded, headheight=114pt,marginparwidth=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[quiet]{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[block=none,style=philosophy-modern]{biblatex}

\usepackage{titling}
%\usepackage{fontenc} % don't load it
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{draftcopy}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xspace}
%\usepackage{xltxtra} % don't load it
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{etoolbox} % already loaded by xpatch
\usepackage[final,ulem=normalem]{changes}
\usepackage{cleveref} % should be last

% languages
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguages{arabic,greek,english,german} 
% fonts
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Scheherazade}

% bibliographies
\addbibresource{my.bib}
\nocite{*}

% settings
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
    \posttitle{%
        \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.4em}%
}

% meta data
\title{\textbf{\emph{My title}, cor gentile}}
\subtitle{my subtitle}
\author{author\\
    email: my mail} 
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{bla}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank for your kind and rapid  answer. I am new to latex and should  learn more. I will try to find some  online help to know how to put in right order the packages